# Dynamic dropdown search directive with angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I'm trying to implement something like [this](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/Ech5wG).
I don't want the multiselect part of it. Just a dropdown which has a search box and based on the data I enter into my search box it must filter my options in the dropdown list. I have implemented the same using angular 1 but I am really confused using angular 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of stuff on this subject. 
Anyway, there is two way to do it :

### 1. Custom directive

```
import { Directive, HostBinding, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDropdown]'
})
export class DropdownDirective {
  @HostBinding('class.menu-open') isOpen = false;

  @HostListener('click') toggleOpen() {
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
  }
}
```

And the according css class :

```
.menu-open > .dropdown-menu {
  visibility: visible !important;
  display: block !important;
}
```

### 2. NgxBootstrap

install `ngx-bootstrap` and `bootstrap`

```
npm install ngx-bootstrap bootstrap --save
```

open `src/app/app.module.ts` and add

```
import { BsDropdownModule} from 'ngx-bootstrap';
...
@NgModule({
   ...
   imports: [BsDropdownModule.forRoot(), ... ],
    ... 
})``
```

open `.angular-cli.json` and insert a new entry into the styles array

```
  ``"styles": [
     "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "styles.css",
  ],``
```

in your component

```
``<div class="btn-group" dropdown>
  <button dropdownToggle type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">
    Button dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider dropdown-divider"></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>``
```

Source : https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/dropdowns

Comment: On your source page it doesn't say it enables search. does it?